# Rear Case Fan makes weird noise

Tags: fan, desktop-computer, cooling, noise

1-2 months ago, I opened my PC case to dust off the components. I wanted to dust off the rear case fan, so I unscrewed the 4 screws holding it to the case. However, I realized that I didn't know what way to put the fan back in. I put it back in with the side with the sticker facing inside the case, since I don't remember seeing a sticker on the back of the PC. I screwed the fan back on and I turned on the PC. When I turned on the PC, the fan made weird whirring noises. This problem persists to this day. Maybe the bearing in the fan broke?

Audio file below (Turn up your volume):
https://mega.nz/#!gIVGkArT!xrmEaAfhwVgLGPQRp1Qb-Oyd0WMxlOfMqJ6du8YGC2w

Comment: Check and see if the cable is not touching the fan. Also, air is moving towards the sticker. So if you want to blow air out of the case, turn the fan around.

Comment: Replace the fan.